# Where did I go wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInsertNewPacks]
    @T_ID INT OUT,
    @BatchNumber VARCHAR(30) OUT,
    @Count INT OUT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @I INT = 1
    DECLARE @ID INT = 0
    DECLARE @ID1 VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PackID VARCHAR(50)

    SELECT @PackID = MAX(PackID) 
    FROM tblPacks

    WHILE @I <= @Count
    BEGIN
        IF @PackID IS NULL
        BEGIN
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status)
            VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                    CAST(('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID) <=3 THEN   CAST(RIGHT(0.001 * @ID, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(20)) END)) as VARCHAR(50)), 0)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @ID1 = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), MAX(PackID)) FROM tblPacks
            SET @I = @I + 1
            SET @ID = @ID + 1

            SELECT MAX(PackID) as ID FROM tblPacks

            INSERT INTO tblPacks (T_ID, BatchNumber, PackID, Status)
            VALUES (@T_ID, @BatchNumber,
                    --CAST(('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID1) <=3 THEN   CAST(RIGHT(0.001*@ID1, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID1 AS VARCHAR(20)) END)) as VARCHAR(50)) 
                   ('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID1) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*@ID1, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID1 AS VARCHAR(20)) END)), 0)
        END
    END
END
```

Then I wrote:

```
EXEC spInsertNewPacks 1, '101', 4
```

and got this output:

```
T_ID    BatchNumber PackID  Status
1   101 PK001   0
1   101 PK002   0
1   101 PK003   0
1   101 PK004   0
```

It is working fine but when I wrote another EXEC command :

```
EXEC spInsertNewPacks 2, '102', 3
```

I am getting:

```
T_ID    BatchNumber PackID  Status
1            101    PK001   0
1            101    PK002   0
1            101    PK003   0
1            101    PK004   0
2            102    PKPK004 0
2            102    PKPKPK004   0
2            102    PKPKPKPK004 0
```

But it has to be:

```
T_ID    BatchNumber PackID  Status
    1            101    PK001   0
    1            101    PK002   0
    1            101    PK003   0
    1            101    PK004   0
    2            102    PK005   0
    2            102    PK006   0
    2            102    PK007   0
```

Where did I go wrong - any ideas? I tried declaring ID as @ID1 as varchhar but it didn't work

Comment: You should substring the PackId first or say remove PK from ID before add it into ID1

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change one sentence that is:

```
SELECT @ID1=CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MAX(PackID)) FROM tblPacks
```

To

```
SELECT @ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MID(MAX(PackID),4)) FROM tblPacks
```

And

```
  CAST(('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID) <=3 THEN   CAST(RIGHT(0.001*@ID, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(20)) END)) as VARCHAR(50))
```

This will work for you.

Comment: It shows an error "Incorrect syntax near ','." at line :-SELECT @ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),( CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MAX(PackID)) , 0 , 2)) FROM tblPacks

Answer (score 0):

In your Else statement you have logic as below:

```
SELECT @ID1=CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),MAX(PackID)) FROM tblPacks
```

Which will give you varchar (string) value like : PK004

Then after you append it with 'PK' as below which result to : PKPK004

```
 ('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID1) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*@ID1, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID1 AS VARCHAR(20)) END))
```

**Conclusion:** I think you have to use `@ID` instead of `@ID1` in else statement, so it will give you proper output

Answer (score 0):

In your Else statement you have logic as below:

```
SELECT @ID = CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), replace(MAX(PackID),'PK','')) FROM tblPacks
```

and values of PackID also change from @ID1 to @ID

```
('PK'+ (CASE WHEN len(@ID) <=3 THEN CAST(RIGHT(0.001*@ID, 3) AS VARCHAR(20)) ELSE CAST(@ID AS VARCHAR(20)) END)), 0)
```

As i am unable to edit above answer. so i am adding new Answer please refer this one.